# Laragon proxy setting wordpress download

Tags: wordpress, proxy, set, laragon

when installing laragon on windows and taking WordPress it gives an error message
(no file: c:\laragon\tm\20220329104527.wordpress.latest.tar.gz)

I'm trying to open apps like WordPress